# how to configure a linux machine to broadcast the incoming traffic

Tags: linux, networking, pcap

I want to configure a linux machine so that it can broadcast all the traffic received by it to other linux machine (in this case the connected nodes). Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

The `ettercap` utility offers this functionality, via its `--bridge` parameter.

Man page : http://linux.die.net/man/8/ettercap

Project page : https://ettercap.github.io/ettercap